# Custom tpl not being applied in user register form which is included by inline registration

Tags: theming, forms

I've created a custom template for user register form and added theme hooks for it.
It works great when I browse to registration page.

However, when the form is used as inline form with Inline Registration module it won't use my custom template.

Why it won't follow theme rules? As far as I known in Drupal theme is the last one called while rendering pages so the rendered output should be according to theme.